# Differential pairs / Single ended and the need for baluns

Tags: rf, transformer, differential, transmission-line, balun

Excuse any blatant mistakes, I'm very *clearly* learning this new. Anyway from a purely transmission line perspective, it seems you can have a single ended line and a differential pair. I see the single ended (like coax line), where the return path is the shield/ground; at first looking as if this is DC, it would mean I would read 0 potential difference between the shield and the ground of *say the radio transmitter*. But in the RF world I would assume for the field between the shield and center piece to propagate in coax or on a PCB, the line would sort of induce current on the return path/shield meaning at each point the shield wouldn't actually be 0 V (if you pronged into where the skin effect is) between it and *say the radio transmitter* but in sort of opposite to the center feed / trace's voltage.

Now when I think of differential pairs, I don't actually see any difference in my mind. When I see images online of waveforms its pretty clear it is trying to get to the point that these opposing signals swing around a reference point but I don't see how that is any different.

I noticed on the an RF transceiver (*cant remember the name sorry*) had its transmit outputs as N and P requiring a balun for coax, so I'm clearly missing something. My only thought is say the N would instantaneously output +4V (wrt ground), whilst the P outputs -4V (wrt ground), but again I don't see how this changes thing along the transmission line.

Essentially I'd like to know the exact difference between the single end and differential pair, and if this is dependent of thinking in hf terms or simple dc cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A load is balanced if both terminals of the load have the same impedance to ground. A signal generator / transmitter / line driver is balanced likewise, that is, both terminals of the signal generator / transmitter / line driver have the same impedance to ground.

A transmission line is *balanced* if it is the case that if the two conductors were to be driven in parallel with a single voltage signal, the current in each conductor would be the same. Examples would include twisted pair and twin-lead.

A transmission line is *unbalanced* if it is the case that if the two conductors were to be driven in parallel with a single voltage signal, the currents in the two conductors would be different. An example would be a coaxial cable.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY5N71.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am using the definitions for balanced and unbalanced transmission lines used in [imbalance difference modeling of mode conversion](https://learnemc.com/introduction-to-imbalance-difference-modeling#:%7E:text=Mode%20conversion%20occurs%20only%20when,will%20experience%20significant%20mode%20conversion.).

> Essentially I'd like to know the exact difference between the single end and differential pair

I believe that what you are referring to as "single end" and "differential pair", are *unbalanced* and *balanced* transmission lines.

The physical distinction between them is related to how current would be divided between the conductors if the conductors are driven in parallel.

An center-fed dipole antenna is a balanced load. A coaxial cable is an unbalanced transmission line. When connecting them together, a balun is used.

In normal operation a high frequencies, a coaxial cable has current on the outer surface of the inner conductor, and on the inner surface of the outer conductor. If a balun is not used to connect the coaxial cable to the balanced load, current will flow on the *outer* surface of the *outer* conductor. This will make the coaxial cable an unintended antenna. This will radiate power, but not necessarily in the desired direction or polarization of the dipole antenna. Similarly, the currents in arms of the dipole antenna will not be equal, and so the antenna will radiate *less* power.

> ...and if this is dependent of thinking in hf terms or simple dc cases.

The effects of transmission line imbalance become much more pronounced at higher frequencies.

However, twisted pair and coaxial cables have different *noise*
properties at audio frequencies. Twisted pair is good for rejecting magnetically induced noise. Twisted pair will accept electric field induced noise but this will primarily be common mode noise. If differential signaling is used, this common mode noise can be attenuated.

Coaxial cable is susceptible to noise from electric fields, but if the outer conductor is *grounded*, the noise will be shunted away. Thus coaxial cable works better with single-ended signaling. However, if 2 coaxial cables are used, differential signaling is obviously possible.

Comment: Definitely helped. Why is then a lot of people say online that a balun is not 100% nescaserry for dipoles?

Comment: @Georgekirby As mentioned, power radiated by the feed line is not necessarily traveling in the same direction or with the same polarization as power radiated by the antenna. If you want your antenna to do its job as it was designed, use a balun. If you don't mind your coax being an antenna and your antenna being inefficient, then you don't need a balun.

Comment: But if the current from the pole thats connected to the coax shield entirley goes on the outer shield, isn’t that litteraly half the power wasted and youd just effectively have a monopole?

Comment: Power is only "wasted" if it is turned into heat. Power that travels down the outside of the outer conductor is largely radiated. Some will turn into heat. Also, the transmitter may actually transmit less power do to the apparent impedance of the coax not seeming right to the amplifier. So yes, there are definite drawbacks to not using a balun. But is a balun absolutely necessary? No. Do I suggest using one? Absolutely.

Comment: Thankyou, ive seen some V-dipoles online that have the coax wrapped around a ferrite, im assuming this chokes the current in the outer shield to prevent this, but that chocked current, does this sort of get used as heat or bounce back into the pole?

Comment: Comments are really not for extended discussions. Your last question is really too far away from your original question.

Comment: Agreed ill post this in a new question soon

Comment: But in response to your main response, i dont understand “ A transmission line is unbalanced if it is the case that if the two conductors were to be driven in parallel with a single voltage signal, the currents in the two conductors would be different” , how is a difference in current possible between the center and the inner layer of the sheild? Would this not be violating some law?

Comment: @Georgekirby no law is violated. See the schematic in my answer. The two conductors are connected in parallel. One wire is not the return path for the other wire. The return path is elsewhere.

Comment: Ive never seen this arrangment before, but im assuming then that its just illustrating the impedances of the sheild and center are difference? But even then how can a wave propgate between two paths if there is no equal go and return?, in fairness andy below did say the inductance on the sheild is zero so i think i understand a little more now. Thanks for the explination. Ive just posted another question on how this works in terms of the antenns too

Comment: @Georgekirby There *is* a "go" and "return". The circuit in my answer is a complete circuit. Identical ground symbols indicate the same node in a schematic unless they are labeled somehow to indicate that they are different grounds. So the return path in my schematic is through the ground node.

Comment: Oh i see now my apologies, i see now. So if in the high frequency world like in your circuit and theres different currents flowing in the sheild and the center line, ive seen online this difference riadiates away, is this true?

Comment: @Yes. Common mode currents cause radiation.

Answer (score 1):

> *in the RF world I would assume for the field between the shield and
> center piece to propagate in coax or on a PCB, the line would sort of
> induce current on the return path/shield meaning at each point the
> shield wouldn't actually be 0 V*

From the question entitled [how are unbalanced coaxial cables used for broadcasting TV signals without any problems?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/458184/20218) I quote myself with a few sentences highlighted: -

> If you do the math on the external fields produced by a regular signal
> sent down a coax and analysed the fields from send and return currents
> individually, you find that at all points outside the shield, the
> opposing magnetic fields exactly cancel to zero. **There is no magnetic
> field outside a coax from a regular coax signal**.
>
> The impact of this is that the signal’s magnetic field is only
> produced in the gap between inner and outer shield. **A repercussion of
> this is that the shield therefore has to have zero inductance**. This is
> because the outer magnetic field is zero (aka zero induction) and the
> signal’s internal magnetic field has no effect on a tubular conductor
> (aka shield) hence, the shield behaves like an infinitely thick ground
> casing surrounding the inner.
>
> That may be a little hard to swallow but if you go back to the
> theories of magnetic fields associated with a tubular flow of current,
> an external field is produced but no inner field. **The reverse is
> entirely true; a magnetic field inside a tube induces no voltage along
> the tube** AND, given there is no external field, the shield has zero
> inductance.

So, theoretically, coax is fine but, you still sometimes need a balun (for instance when using a dipole antenna) because clearly, the coax is unbalanced.

Comment: Never really thought of it that way but i think i do (surprisingly) understand that. Maybe its worth me posting a separate question for this but why exactly is the balun needed for dipole? If the one of the poles is attached to the shield, id assume one of the poles is sort of 180 out of phase of the other?, so could this sort of act as a differential pair (between the inner part of the shield and the center peice)?

Comment: A dipole needs a balanced feed. A monopole (i.e. rubber duck or whip) is a monopole and suits coax.

Comment: But why? As ive been told comments shouldnt extend beyond the original question and ive come to a similar question from the answer below. Ill post a related question soon. Appreciate the help

Comment: @Georgekirby if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: "The reverse is entirely true; a magnetic field inside a tube induces no voltage along the tube AND, given there is no external field, the shield has zero inductance" when you say induces no voltage , are you reffering to the voltage on the outer layer of the shield?

Comment: I'm referring to the voltage developed across the opposite ends of the shield (end to end).

Comment: When you said the sheild has 0 inductance, is this why when deriving the telegraph equation, the line at the bottom dosent have inductance , its only on the top line that does and obvs the capaictance between the two? Or is that just some mathematical simplification

Comment: There are many versions of the drawing that shows the interconnection of the RLGC components but, they all boil down down to the simple version and no, there is no connection with coax shield having zero inductance.